How to count swung eights in takadimi?
If I understand correctly, swung eights work kind of like triplets when the first two notes of the triplet are combined giving in result: two notes — long; and then the last from the triplet, short.
Ok, but then how do I count them in takadimi? As regular eights? "Ta di"? Or from triplet perspective — "ta da"? Or "ta-a da"?

It never worked for me: el-e-phant does. So does Hump-ty dump-ty!

TL;DR: The method doesn't specify how to execute swung rhythm, so it's up to the teacher or student to decide on the method to use.

Takadimi does not specify a counting method for swing rhythms. Jazz/swing is not mentioned in the foundational article "Takadimi: A Beat-Oriented System of Rhythm Pedagogy" (Richard Hoffman, William Pelto, and John W. White, Journal of Music Theory Pedagogy [1994]), and Richard Hoffman's The Rhythm Book mentions it only briefly, without giving specific guidance.

The next three exercises have off-beat and syncopated rhythms characteristic of jazz styles developed in the United States in the early twentieth century. Jazz rhythms are not always [performed] exactly as written, but sometimes "swing." Your instructor may ask you to perform these rhythms as written, then in a more idiomatic jazz style.

I suppose the implication is that Hoffman is expecting the "as written" syllables to be used when swinging.
IMO, either way has its benefits. By using "ta di", one reinforces that it's eighth notes being performed: "this is how eighth notes should sound when swinging." But by using "ta-a da", one reinforces the actual performed rhythm, which reinforces the idea that in swing music one doesn't perform eighth notes in the "classical" style.
My personal preference: use "ta di". This way there's no confusion if the piece also contains written triplets.

Many thanks for the full explanation. Side note remark, funny, because I thought switching from my too-many-syllables native language to takadimi I solved the problems, and now this... :-).
